# Script to get domain's SSL expiry date

Tags: bash, shell

I want to create a bash script that takes url as an argument.
for ex: ./scriptname https://domainame.com/

Current one works with with domainname.com but not with the full URL.

I get this error when I try to enter the full URL,

unable to load certificate
140398535546784:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:707:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE

This is the one I have currently have,

```
#!/bin/bash
echo | openssl s_client -connect $1:443 2> /dev/null | \
  openssl x509 -noout -enddate | \
cut -d = -f 2
```

Comment: Your script is good as we should use openssl s_client -connect host:port, not a full url. This is specified in https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man1/s_client.html

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is to cut the parts of protocol and path out of the url

```
#!/bin/bash¬
NoProtocol="${1//https:\/\//}"¬
DomainOnly="${NoProtocol%%/*}"¬
¬
echo | openssl s_client -connect ${DomainOnly}:443 2> /dev/null | \¬
  openssl x509 -noout -enddate | \¬
cut -d = -f 2¬
```